# How to select a diode with enough reverse voltage in buck DCDC regulator?

Tags: power, diodes, dc-dc-converter

Is there any experience on selecting the proper reverse voltage on asynchronous buck regulator?

I want MP2451(Vin 36V max) to work well in a wide range of input voltage(5-24V) and convert it into 3.3V, will a 1N5819 with reverse voltage of 40V meets needing? Or a larger redundancy is needed?
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Thinks about the conditions which the diode will experience, the diode will experience the maximum reverse voltage when the SW output of the IC is connected to Vin. So 40 Volts will be enough as the IC can handle 36 V max. So the MP2451 would be damaged even before the diode is at risk.

Comment: Yes. But can the diode work stably enough when the voltage of its double sides reaches nearly its maximum reverse voltage?

Comment: *the voltage of its double sides reaches...* I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean: "If the cathode voltage gets close to the maximum reverse voltage ?" Yes of course that is OK, this diode is specified for a reverse voltage of 40 V so as long as you do not exceed that 40 V you will not break it. What would be the use of specifying that a diode can handle 40 V but it actually breaks at 35 V ??? That would be a useless diode !!!!